# iTunes Connect, "Missing Screenshot" message

Tags: ios

I'm trying to submit the latest build of my app through iTunes Connect, and it is being rejected due to "Missing Screenshot". More specifically, when I click on the message it says.

`Missing Localized Screenshots`

`French`

`English`

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the fact that I only have 3.5 inch retina screenshots and no 4.0 inch ones required by the iPhone 5.

My question is, since I don't have my app optimized to fit the iPhone 5's screen, should I just upload my 3.5 inch screenshots with the missing part on the bottom set to black? This is indeed how our app looks on the iPhone 5 at the moment, is this enough?

Comment: Did you setup localization when you created the app in i-tunes connect?

Comment: Yes and I have screenshots for 3.5 inch retina for both English and French.

Comment: You are required to provide for both sizes. I believe...

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=19813

Comment: Actually this one is better: http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/app-store/app-store-submissions-now-require-iphone-5-screenshots-developers/

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I am of the feeling that if something can be discussed or answered quickly, just answer it instead of trying to waste resources on getting it removed. It was fairly simple, the app was rejected because the SO didnt know that iPhone 5 screenshots are required. And there is a good chance someone else will have the same issue or question.

Comment: Great, @logixologist, then you won't mind helping me with my question about changing the toner cartridge in my printer!

Comment: @JoshCaswell LOL... I'm just trying not to always put up barriers. Many people dont ask the question quite right but its a valid question and the powerhouses with thousands in reputation instead of guiding them will throw them into DownVote Hell. I have downvoted myself but that is when its so off topic or is a "give me code" request (usually when they are not even giving you a description or screen shot and asking for functionality in XYZ Appp). Sorry PaulG for hijacking this post.

Comment: My fault, I've been on SO long enough to know the rules about non-programming specific questions and I do admit that my question is not programming-specific. I do appreciate the help and I apologize for going against the guidelines. By the way, I ended up just modifying my UI using autoresize and constraints, wasn't really that hard. Now everything fits properly on 3.5 and 4 inch screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit an app that does not support iPhone 5 anymore. You should make your app 4" retina compatible.

Comment: All apps must take advantage of the 4" screen. Letterboxing is the default behavior of all not updated apps. For quite a few months now, all apps need to fully support 4" screens in order to be submitted. It is not that hard to support it, especially if you use autolayout and constraints (meaning you support ios 6 and above).

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer submit apps that do not support iPhone5 screens, hence you need to also provide the iPhone 5 screenshots.